# DataTables server-side processing

Tags: jquery

I have a code:

```
function prepareListCustomer() {
    var req;
    req = new AjaxAdapter;
    req.dataType = 'json';
    return req.query('GET', LIST_CUSTOMER_URL, {rowsOnPage: k, page: l}, function(responseServer, status, xhr) {
        listCustomer = responseServer.dataListCustomer;
        l = l + 1;
      }, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          var exception;
          exception = jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
          return showError(exception);
        });
}

function prepareDataTable() {
    $('#displayData').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": LIST_CUSTOMER_URL
        "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
          oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
            "dataType": 'json',
            "type": "GET",
            "url": LIST_CUSTOMER_URL,
            "data": {rows: k, pages: l},
            "success": prepareListCustomer
          } );
        }
      } );
}
```

Function prepareListCustomer() write data to listCustomre. I want display this data in prepareDataTable, how?
I want use server-side processing. In listCustomer I have JSON like:

```
{
    "rowsPerPage": 10,
    "page": 1,
    "total": 100,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "nazwa1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "nazwa2"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "nazwa3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am reading http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html But I don't know how implement to my code?

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON doesn't look like the default.

If you use that JSON you need to declare each column on the javascript call like this after the sAjaxSource property.

```
"aoColumns": [
    { "mDataProp": "DBColumn1" , "bSortable":true, "bVisible": false },
    { "mDataProp": "DBColumn2" , "bSortable":true, "bVisible": false },
    { "mDataProp": "DBColumn3" , "bSortable":true, "bVisible": false }
]
```

Also this part of the JSON is incorrect

```
"rowsPerPage": 10,
"page": 1,
"total": 100,
"rows":
```

It should look like this

```
"sEcho": 1,
"iTotalRecords": 100,
"iTotalDisplayRecords": 10,
"aaData":
```

If you look at the PHP example on the link you posted it generates this headings here and puts them into an associative array.

```
/*
 * Output
 */
$output = array(
    "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
    "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
    "aaData" => array()
);
```

Then starts loading all data into that array before encoding to JSON

```
while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
{
    $row = array();
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
        {
            /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
            $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
        else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
        {
            /* General output */
            $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
    }
    $output['aaData'][] = $row;
}

echo json_encode( $output );
```

And your JSON should look something like this

```
{
   "sEcho":8,
   "iTotalRecords":1,
   "iTotalDisplayRecords":1,
   "aaData":[
      {
         "Entity_Id":840982,
         "External_Id":"1",
         "Family_Name":"A",
         "First_Name":"A",
         "Prefix_Title":null,
         "Suffix_Title":null
      }
   ]
}
```

There's a full explanation here on [DataTables.net](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html)